# In the US, are the assets of a vulnerable elderly person transferred to the custodian?

Tags: realism, i-care-a-lot

After I watched *I Care a Lot,* this question came to mind.

In the movie, a woman (Marla), who is a scammer, locates wealthy old people and convinces the court to give her guardianship over them and move them to assisted living facilities through false testimonies by corrupt doctors.

Once she becomes the guardian of a person, their assets belong to her, and she sells them to make huge money (from house to car to jewels). This is actually what she does for a living.

Well, first of all, I am not a US citizen to know about the law there, but it seems unreal to me that the assets of those vulnerable old people belong to the guardian after the court decides to give them custodianship. However, there’s always a probability that the guardians are scammers and sell the assets for their own benefit. And for the case in this movie, it’s what Marla always does, so how isn’t she revealed anytime? How doesn’t her huge income reveal she is a scammer? A guardian doesn’t make huge money in their job.

**My Question**: In the US, do the assets of vulnerable old people belong to their appointed custodians?

Comment: No, the ownership of assets do not pass to a guardian.  The guardian can however make decisions on behalf of their ward, which is open to abuse, in any country.

Comment: @iandotkelly But there should be a law to prevent such an abuse.

Comment: But there ARE laws to prevent such an abuse. What she did in the movie IS illegal.

Comment: @iandotkelly Wow! How did you comment on a deleted post? However, while her actions are illegal she is always able to convince the judge to give her guardianship right over others. Also, if there are laws to prevent crimes then why are thefts and murders unstopably happening?

Comment: idk the US structure, but in the UK this is known as "power of attorney" which gives the right of an appointed person the right to sign any legal paperwork/contract etc on behalf of the donor. There are many constrictions, but it has the potential to be abused - https://www.gov.uk/power-of-attorney - Here's a famous case - https://www.ashfords.co.uk/insights/articles/abuse-of-power-of-attorney

Comment: @EtackSxchange Moderators can still comment on deleted posts.

Comment: @F1Krazy What's the purpose for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When old people can no longer manage their finances, a trusted family member or friend may be assigned to help them. This requires proving both the state of the old person (doctors will testify what they can and can't understand) and the trustworthiness of the person. Once this happens, the "guardian" does not **own** the property of the old person, but they do **control** it. They can spend money out of the person's account (for example to pay their bills or buy things the old person needs) and sell the person's property.

A malicious "guardian" could spend the money out of the old person's account for the guardian's own benefit. That is the plot of the movie. Is it plausible? Well, people can have cars and jewels and houses. That doesn't make her a criminal. And the victims she has chosen do not have other friends and family who would notice what is happening. So it's not completely unbelievable that she would get away with it for a while.